# SSCE 4 Unable to load native components exception from outlook plugin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

We have a wpf .net app using SSCE 4 with private deployment and works great

however there's also a outlook plugin which throws up the following exception

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException was caught
>       HResult=-2147467259   Message=Unable to load the native components of
>   SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version
>   8876. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.   Source=""   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   NativeError=-1   StackTrace:

```
     at System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor()
    at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
    at ZKB.initDB() in C:\ZKB\OutlookApi\dbInit.cs:line 42   InnerException:
```

when the following line is executed

```
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(myConnStr());
```

Hooking into Assembly.Resolve shows it trying to locate

System.Data.SqlServerCe.resources, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

and then the exception above comes up

SSCE 4 SP1 is installed on this machine

Any help on what could be wrong and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use private deployment from an Office addin, this will require you to place the sqlce dll files under the location of Outlook.exe (and not even sure that it will Work then)

Comment: that seems reasonable. Would pointing to the right dll assembly.Resolve work ? I tried it but can't resolve why it continues to look for 4.0.0.1 version still when it does not exist in any .config on the device ?

Comment: Do you have a referfence to the 4.0.0.1 dll in your addin project, maybe

Comment: hmmm, that's a red herring, SSCE SP1 is installed on this machine but it's failing on loading native binaries, any clues on where to look ?

Comment: Nope, not without sitting in front of your PC with a VS debugger and Sysinternals process monitor

Comment: Reinstalling sscev4 sp1 seemed to have fixed it, i had installed ssce 3.5 to get sqlcetoolbox to work, that seems to be the problem, anyhoo it works now, thanks for all your help and for all your work on sqlcetoolbox !